# How to find sessions stored in Mongo via MongoStore?

Tags: node.js, express-session, passport.js

I'm using express-session along with passport and MongoStore to store my sessions. They're obviously being stored in the MongoDB, how can I access them just to take a look at? There's no business value in this it's just from a theoretical/technical perspective that I'm interested, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run mongo shell with command:

```
mongo
```

Create a new connection:

```
conn = new Mongo()
```

Access your DB:

```
db = conn.getDB('myDB')
```

This command displays the sessions (inside the inprog array, look at the objects with client):

```
db.currentOP(true)
```